# Выбор альтернативного сервиса при отказе основного.

Tags: c#, wcf, очередь, cluster

Реализуем кластерное решение для wcf сервисов. Подскажите есть ли какое-нибудь проверенное решение для проверки доступности другого сервиса и выбора альтернативного, при отказе основного. 
Например. 
На wcf сервис приходят сообщения от клиента и он их ставит в очередь. Очередь реализовала на отдельном сервере и отдельным сервисом. Если этот сервис с очередью выйдет из строя, нужно отправлять сообщения на резервный сервис, определенный заранее. Есть ли какие-то красивые решения для реализации в автоматическом режиме по средствам wcf или проверять в коде доступность одного сервиса и так далее?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Про штатные средства для подобных проверок в WCF я не слышал (точнее, слышал о [WS-Discovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456791(v=vs.110).aspx), начиная с .NET 4.0, но не пробовал и не уверен, что оно вообще подходит). Поэтому расскажу про велосипеды.

### Нужно быстро узнавать о падении стороннего сервиса

Суть в периодическом "пинге" сервиса. Заводите таймер/отдельный поток, который проверяет доступность сервиса. Если сервис недоступен, имеет смысл сделать дополнительные 2-3 попытки с возрастающим интервалом между ними (как и в случае со всеми остальными методами), поскольку могут быть кратковременные перебои в сети. Если в итоге сервис не отвечает, производите операцию переключения (меняете адрес сервиса на дополнительный и делаете все остальные вещи, которые могут быть с этим связаны). Повторные попытки, само собой, нужно делать при получении определенных исключений (например, `CommunicationException`).

#### Контроля над сторонним сервисом нет

Если сервис не предлагает специально предназначенной для проверки статуса операции (типа `Ping()`, `Heartbeat()`, `CheckStatus()` и т.д.), то можно запрашивать его метаданные:

```
bool isServiceUp = true;
try
{
   string address = "http://server/Service.svc?wsdl";
   var mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(
       new Uri(address),
       MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet);
   mexClient.GetMetadata();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // если сервис недоступен, получим исключение
    isServiceUp = false;
}
```

#### Контроль над сторонним сервисом есть

В сервис добавляется "проверочный" метод (`Ping()`/`Heartbeat()`/`CheckStatus()`). В самом простом варианте этот метод пуст, но он также может возвращать и данные о своем состоянии (особенно если внутри себя он использует несколько разных систем - БД, другой сервис и т.д.).

### О падении сервиса достаточно узнавать в момент его вызова

В этом случае все несколько проще, потому что вам не нужно специально проверять сервис. Если при очередном вызове сервиса он не ответил, пробуете еще 2-3 раза. Если после этого сервис не ответил, производите операцию переключения и снова пробуете сделать вызов.

---

Какой бы вариант вы не выбрали, вам понадобятся следующие блоки:

- код переключения сервисов (как минимум подмена одного адреса на другой)
- обобщенный код повтора операций, чтобы любой метод можно было вызвать как
  `InvokeWithRetry(() => SomeMethod())`
- обобщенный код, который соединяет эти два блока вместе и вызывает
  переключение сервисов в случае необходимости

Comment: WS-Discovery это протокол обмена сообщениями для обнаружения сервисов, похож на SMTP и подобные, и сам по себе задачу не решит. Но его можно приспособить для этой цели, т.к. отчасти он описывает и предложенные вами модели. Подробнее тут http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/ws-discovery.pdf